# Detect and Change display resolution permanently using java

Tags: java

How to detect and change display resolution permanently using java?

Comment: Is this like one of those 90's websites that had detailed instructions on the front page for resizing your browser window and changing all your default fonts, "to maximise your experience on our website"?

Answer (score 2):

Getting the resolution is easy:

```
// Get the default toolkit
Toolkit toolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();

// Get the current screen size
Dimension scrnsize = toolkit.getScreenSize();
```

I don't know if it's even possible to change it from Java though, at least without using JNI.

Comment: That only tells you the resolution of the primary display. See `GraphicsEnvironment.getScreenDevices()`, `GraphicsDevice.getConfigurations()` and `GraphicsConfiguration.getBounds()`